# method is not defined when trying to use it as a static method

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to use static method in order to use it externally.

utils file:

```js
'use strict'
function utils(){}
utils.staticMethod1 = function(){
alert("foo");
};
module.exports =  utils();
```

Main file:

```js
'use strict;'
     let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');
let utilsPage = require('../utils/utils.js');
    describe("login to website",function(){
         let employeeId;
         let employeeBday;
         let home = new HomePage();
         
      beforeEach(function(){
           
            browser.driver.get("http://foo.com/");     
        });
       
            it("should succees picking a present",function(){
                utilsPage.staticMethod1();
        });
    });
```

But I'm keep getting an error says: `Failed: utils is not defined`

Comment: `this` in a (supposed) static method does not make sense! Also, if you;re going to use stacksnippets to demonstrate the problem - make sure they work (ie, do something and dont error)

Comment: How do you import utils file?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - for that matter i dont even see how `utils` is *exported*

Comment: I didn't import utils file. I thought using utils.staticMethod1(); will do the work.

Comment: @Jamiec That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @YanivEliav see that `let HomePage = require('../page/home_page.js');` - thats importing the code from `home_page.js` - you need to do similar for your utils.

Comment: @YanivEliav "method is not defined ..." well it seems the whole `utils` object is not defined. It was declared in another file and neither been somehow imported nor has exports inside. How do you expect engine to magically know about `utils` object.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I'm being criticized here but i'm probably deserved it. did what you guys suggested. I'm a newbie. now the error says that utils.staticMethod1(); is not a function

Comment: @YanivEliav Could you plz show updated code. The one that actually throws the exception saying "utils.staticMethod1(); is not a function"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I have updated my post

Comment: @YanivEliav `utils()` returns undefined. So `module.exports = utils()` is just `module.exports = undefined`. So again `utilsPage ` is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page file:

```
'use strict';

var Utils = function(){
   this.methodTest = function(){
      console.log("Something"); //alert(this);
   };
};

module.exports = Utils;
```

Your Spec file:

```
'use strict;'

let Utils = require('../page/utils.Page.js');

describe("login to website",function(){
     let employeeId;
     let employeeBday;
     let utils = new Utils();

     beforeEach(function(){ 
         browser.driver.get("http://foo.com/");     
     });

     it("should success picking a present",function(){
         utils.methodTest();
         expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('SomethingToGetAnError');
     });

});
```

You should peek a bit about using static methods in protractor, they would lead you to rough ends.

[Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40096082/3926599)

[Better explanation about Page Objects Pattern in testing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761859/3926599)

Comment: In general I do use page object pattern, but needed an external file to use for some other reasons.

Comment: If you need yo use an external file such as Information to be used against forms, you should load it like loading a json file into testing. F.Ex: `browser.params.users  = require('./shared.params.' + countryCode + '.json').users;`

Comment: I used your code but getting an error.  Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'method' of undefined

Comment: @YanivEliav change the page function to return actually something that protractor can handle. Such as a console.log and implement some expectation into the Spec file `Edited post with this elements`